# parskip (or line spacing) for conversations

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing, parskip

I post the example here to illustrate what i want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\section*{default}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
This is the 1st line.
This should be the 2nd line, with small space to the 1st line (about 3pt).

This should be the 3rd line, with large space to the 2nd line (about 10pt).
\section*{manually modified to get what i want}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
He told her:

- Bla bla.\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

She asked:\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}

- What did you mean?\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

So, when I type in tex source:

```
He told her:
- I don't have time.
```

there should not be 1 line, but 2 lines with a space about 3pt between them. Is there anyway to do that for the whole document without reset the `parskip` everytime?